# Search table javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I search for the column `random ID` in the table, I can only search for the values in the `unique ID` column. What seems to be the error?

Sample Code:

```
<table>
        <tr><th>Unique ID</th><th>Random ID</th></tr>
        <tr><td>214215</td><td>442</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1252512</td><td>556</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2114</td><td>4666</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3245466</td><td>334</td></tr>
        <tr><td>24111</td><td>54364</td></tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>


$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:nth-child(2)` instead of `:first` to get the second td and not the first one:

more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nth-child` property.

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr><th>Unique ID</th><th>Random ID</th></tr>
        <tr><td>214215</td><td>442</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1252512</td><td>556</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2114</td><td>4666</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3245466</td><td>334</td></tr>
        <tr><td>24111</td><td>54364</td></tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```